# jQuery -- .append is appending html element, then automatically the html is being removed

Tags: jquery, append

When using the below code to append div and p elements inside the .container (using value within inputs), the elements are being created and automatically destroyed. Any ideas as to what is wrong? Thanks a bunch!

```
 $("#submit").on("click", function(event){
    var textTitle = $("#title").val();
    var textContent = $("#content").val();
    $("#title").val("");
    $("#content").val("");
    $(".container").append("<div class='panel panel-default'><h4>" + textTitle + "</h4></div>");
    $(".container").append("<div class='panel panel-default'><p>" + textContent + "</p></div>");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I guess you submit the form and you don't stop the submission, so the page reloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound like your #submit is a input type="submit" and your submitting the form. Because your above code works just fine when not within a form tag.

Also be careful when using .append() because it will lag the browser. Its always best to form all your DOM elements into a HTML string and then use the append function once.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxxu3uhw/1/

```
    $("#submit").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var textTitle = $("#title").val(),
            textContent = $("#content").val();

        $("#title").add("#content").val("");

        var html = "<div class='panel panel-default'><h4>" + textTitle + "</h4></div>"
                 + <div class='panel panel-default'><p>" + textContent + "</p></div>

        $(".container").append(html);
    });
```

Reply back with more specific examples of your currently structure and I can better help.

If you are using a form and input type="submit" then add the event.preventDefault() and you will not submit the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The form was definitely submitting. I guess I was thinking that since I didn't include a method or action on the form, it shouldn't submit...

Comment: Why did you do $("#title").add("#content").val(""); instead of simply $("#title").val("");        and       $("#content").val(""); ?

Comment: I guess personal preference. Keeping all elements that get the same treatment grouped together.

Another way would be something as simple as $("#title, #content).val("");

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault` in place of `event.stopPropogation`, let it prevent the default working of form submission.